# Questions regarding regular expressions and wild cards and grep

Tags: bash, unix

1)For instance, find any line that begins with a capital letter and ends with a period uses the following expression:

`$ grep "^[A-Z].*\.$" demo.txt` -- 1

what is the difference between `grep '^[A-Z].*\.$' demo.txt` and expression 1(using single quotes, I tried it and it seems the same)

what is the difference between `grep '^[A-Z]*\.$' demo.txt` and expression 1(what is the period for?)

2)To find each line in the file that contains an opening and closing parenthesis, with only letters and single spaces in between, uses
`$ grep "([A-Za-z ]*)" demo.txt`, is there another way to represent the same thing using `{}`?
something like `$ grep "([A-Za-z ]\{...\})" demo.txt`

3)Assume we want to search the contents of a text file called letter.txt, for the number of times a line began with one of these words: DO, DOO, or DOOO. How do we use the grep command(using only a single switch,cannot use them or, and using the single quotes)
I tried something like this `grep -c '^D(O){1,3}' letter.txt` it seems not right.

Comment: Please format your post. Use backticks \` `to put stuff in code blocks` or indent it with 4 spaces.

Comment: My bad, I have formatted it already. Thanks

Comment: What is `-- 1` doing in `grep "^[A-Z].*\.$" demo.txt -- 1`?

Comment: sorry expression 1 so that I don't need to type it everytime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> using single quotes, I tried it and it seems the same)

The quoting changes how the **shell** parses the arguments. See [Difference between single and double quotes in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash)

> what is the period for?)

To match any character. The `*` matches the preceding character or group zero or more times, so `.*` matches anything. Research what is a "regular expression". Regular expression is not shell globbing, see `man 7 regex` vs `man 7 glob`.

> is there another way to represent the same thing using {}?

As far as I understand the question, no. `(` is character represented by `(`, not by `{`, so I do not understand how to match `(` with `{`...

> DO, DOO, or DOOO. How do we use the grep command(using only a single switch,cannot use them or, and using the single quotes)

I would:

```
grep 'DO'
```

as that matches `DOOO` anyway. If you want to:

```
grep 'DO\|DOO\|DOOO'
```

but if you want to use **bound** you can just:

```
grep 'DO\{1,3\}'
```

> like this grep -c '^D(O){1,3}' letter.txt it seems not right.

Sure, because `(` matches a literal `(` and `{` matches a literal `{`. If you want to represent a group in basic regular expression, escape the `(` `{` characters.

```
# all these lines do the same.
grep 'DO\{1,3\}'
grep 'D\(O\)\{1,3\}'
grep -E 'D(O){1,3}'
grep -E 'DO{1,3}'
```

Research the difference between basic regular expression and extended regular expression.

Comment: Thank you. What does this mean `$ grep '^[A-Z]*\.$' demo.txt` without the period? I get it now that `.*` means anything but I think I am confused with regular expressions and wildcards `*`

Comment: `The * matches the preceding character or group zero or more times` the `[A-Z]*` matches `[A-Z]` zero or more times.

Comment: the command `ls *.d?c` will list something like `something.d_c`. why the period here really means `.`

Comment: `ls *.d?c` the `*` means anything, why would we not use `.*`. Thanks for the help, it is just I feel like I messed somthing up

Comment: if `The * matches the preceding character or group zero or more times`, when I do the command `ls letter1[1-3]*.txt` `letter1.txt` will not be listed ([1-3] zero time

Comment: As I said: `Regular expression is not shell globbing, see man 7 regex vs man 7 glob`. In __shell globbing__ `*` matches anything, in __regular expression__ `*` matches zero or more preceding character or group. They differ __a lot__, and regular expression has also "flavors" - basic, extended and perl regexes. `grep` works with regex, your shell works  with glob.